# How do I make a class in JavaFX 2.0 a usable Node?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX so please don't hesitate to explain basic concepts. I am able to create a simple GUI and I have a `TabPane` with two tabs in my program. My question is how do I create a class that can be used as a node?

For example, `tab.setContent(stuff)` would add `stuff` to a `tab`, `tab` assuming of course that `stuff` is a `Node`. So let's say I create a class called `Clock` and want to add an instance of it to `tab`, how do I do such a thing?

The clock should be a graphical object. I'm new to graphical programming so references to Swing etc. won't be particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, create a class "Clock" and extend it with a layout you wish it to contain. For example:

```
public class Clock extends BorderPane{}
```

Then, you can set properties or other Nodes to it by using a constructor.

```
public class Clock extends BorderPane{
     TextArea ta = new TextArea("This is TOP");
     this.setTop(ta);
     Button b1 = new Button("This is button 1");
     Button b2 = new Button("This is button 2");
     HBox box = new HBox();
     box.getChildren().addAll(b1,b2);
     this.setCenter(box);
}
```

Then, you would call it from your main program as such:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
     primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Clock()));
     primaryStage.show();
}
```

In your case, you would set the Scene when the tab is pressed. That can be done using the Tab class and adding an actionListener to it.

```
tab.setContent(new Clock());
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: In my case the hbox is not recognized after I initialize it.

Comment: In other words this code doesn't compile, am I missing something besides the imports?

Comment: It should work. Make sure to check you imported the right one. import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

Comment: I imported the hbox and I can initialize the hbox just fine but for some reason I can't call any of the methods belonging to hbox or even use the variable after I initialized it.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a method in clock, then also make a constructor that calls this method. put all

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea("This is TOP");
 this.setTop(ta);
 Button b1 = new Button("This is button 1");
 Button b2 = new Button("This is button 2");
 HBox box = new HBox();
 box.getChildren().addAll(b1,b2);
 this.setCenter(box);
```

inside that methode.