# JavaFX can you position panes at coordinates like shapes inside a scene?

Tags: java, javafx

i want to add 3 classes to my main class and all of them extend Pane i.e. all of them are a group of nodes. Now i want to know how do i position them according to my preference at 3 discrete points/coordinates or it was a bad idea to make classes extend pane. Should i do something else?

The existing layouts can't give me that much control over their position as much as i want

here is the image : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6aqsa81vmc0rawq/Screenshot%202017-07-21%2002.37.54.jpg?dl=0

Sorry but this file can't be uploaded to imgur

I got the idea of extending a class to pane from : [How do I make a class in JavaFX 2.0 a usable Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414603/how-do-i-make-a-class-in-javafx-2-0-a-usable-node) , i just want to group certain nodes and shapes together into a class and instantiate whenever i want

Comment: If you want to position the content by hand, just use a `Pane` for the main container and call `setLayoutX()` and `setLayoutY()` on the individual child nodes.

Comment: @James_D why are these methods not in the documentation?? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html

Comment: [Because they are...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setLayoutX-double-) Note that you can also use `relocate()`, as suggested in said documentation.

Comment: @James_D hmmm... i wanted to position a pane so i went to pane. Gotta keep in mind to check the super class from next time and thanks

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend this approach though. If the outer pane is resized, the child nodes won't respond at all. It's better to think about how you want the positions of the child nodes to relate to each other (your image doesn't really capture that information) and use a layout pane that positions them accordingly.

Comment: @James_D i think i will be able to bind my panes too but unsure on how to resize a child node in the running of an application

Comment: Which is why you should use (or, in extreme cases, write) a layout pane.

Comment: @James_D i am a beginner and have read about stuff but not tried it all. should javafx apps be made re-sizeable. I just want to know what do professional developers do? or since there might not be many professional aspects  of javafx programming but still as a beginner trying to showcase my projects on my resume. what would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setLayoutX()` and `setLayoutY()` methods

Comment: @James_D how did you generate that link which scrolled down to a specific position on a page

Comment: I right-clicked on the method name in the documentation and copied the link.

Comment: (Or, you can just go to the [no-frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/overview-summary.html) version of the documentation, navigate to [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html), scroll down and click on the method name, and the URL will be in the browser's location bar.